# Traefik 404 on https://www

Tags: traefik

I'm using this config:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  traefik:
    command:
      # Get Docker as the provider
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      # Avoid that all containers are exposed
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      # Settle the ports for the entry points
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.web-secure.address=:443"
      # Settle the autentification method to http challenge
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myhttpchallenge.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myhttpchallenge.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      # Uncomment this to get a fake certificate when testing
      #- "--certificatesresolvers.myhttpchallenge.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      # Settle letsencrypt as the certificate provider
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myhttpchallenge.acme.email=___________________
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myhttpchallenge.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
  mysite:
    labels:
      # The labels are usefull for Traefik only
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"
      # Get the routes from http
      - "traefik.http.routers.mysite.rule=Host(mysite.com, www.mysite.com)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mysite.entrypoints=web"
      # Redirect these routes to https
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mysite.middlewares=redirect-to-https@docker"
      # Get the routes from https
      - "traefik.http.routers.mysite-secured.rule=Host(mysite.com, www.mysite.com)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mysite-secured.entrypoints=web-secure"
      # Apply autentificiation with http challenge
      - "traefik.http.routers.mysite-secured.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mysite-secured.tls.certresolver=myhttpchallenge"
```

Everything works except https://www. I get an SSL error, then when I click proceed anyway, I get a error from traefik, 404 page not found. http://, https://, http://www all work, redirect to https://. But https://www does not work.

I tried a lot of suggestions, the regex middleware to no success. It's just the exact same results.

Comment: Clearly the route is not working for https://www. Have you tried running in DEBUG mode or accessing the treafik dashboard ? Where are you running website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add backticks around the site name in the Host():

```
- "traefik.http.routers.mysite.rule=Host(`mysite.com`, `www.mysite.com`)"
- "traefik.http.routers.mysite-secured.rule=Host(`mysite.com`, `www.mysite.com`)"
```

Also, my deploy was wrong. Sometimes I was uploading the file ad-hoc, then manually running a post-receive hook which overwrites with an old version.